# Iterating over a JSON object to add values to FormData in jquery

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I have a JSON object in jquery like this :-

```
userObj =
{ 
 "loginId":"abc123", 
 "class":"5", 
 "email":"akhil.gts1997@gmail.com", 
 "level":"1"
}
```

I have to send a POST request to the server with multipart/form-data. I have created a FormData object :-

```
var fd = new FormData();
```

What I need to do is to iterate over each element in the JSON and append them to my variable fd. This is what I want :-

```
fd.append('loginId','abc123');
fd.append('class',5);
fd.append('email','akhil.gts1997@gmail.com');
```

Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate the object using `for`

```js
for (var key in userObj) {
  fd.append(key, userObj[key]);
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: Thank you. I get the data on the server side. But the last element was a nested JSON element :-"userRole":{
  "role":"STU",
  "level":"1"
 }, which doesn't go through. UserRole is null on the server-side whereas it should have been {"role":"STU", "level":"1"}

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
let userObj = { 
 "loginId":"abc123", 
 "class":"5", 
 "email":"akhil.gts1997@gmail.com", 
 "level":"1"
};

let fd = new FormData();

for (let key in userObj){
    fd.append(key, userObj[key])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var userObj = {
    "loginId": "abc123",
    "class": "5",
    "email": "akhil.gts1997@gmail.com",
    "level": "1"
};
var keys = Object.keys(userObj);
var values = Object.values(userObj);
var fd = new FormData();
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    fd.append(keys[i], values[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var userObj =
{ 
 "loginId":"abc123", 
 "class":"5", 
 "email":"akhil.gts1997@gmail.com", 
 "level":"1"
}
var fd = new FormData(); 
$.each(userObj, function(i, val) {
  console.log(i + " " + val);
  fd.append(i, val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Try something like this.
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let userObj = { 
 "loginId":"abc123", 
 "class":"5", 
 "email":"akhil.gts1997@gmail.com", 
 "level":"1"
};

var newdata= new FormData();

 $.each(userObj, function (key, value) {
    newdata.append(key, userObj[key]);
    console.log(key, userObj[key])
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```